# time to execute function

Tags: timer

I am working on a bot (my first project in C#) wich is supposed to click on some images. One of them is going to open a new page and take a picture of it, but because of the delay of opening the page I need a timer to wait for it to load completely.

```
Point location;
bool success;
success = search(Properties.Resources.background, screenshot(), out location);
if (success == true)
{
    execute(location);
    success = search(Properties.Resources.target, screenshot(), out location);
    if (success == true)
    {
        execute(location);
        ///////--------------TIMER 5s------------------///////
        success = search(Properties.Resources.close, screenshot(), out location);
        if (success == true)
        {
            execute(location);
        }
    }
    else
    {
       //code
    }
}
else
{
    //code
}
```

So,

search [the first one] function tells if on the screen is the image called background. If yes clicks on it.

search [the second one] function tells if on the screen is the image called target. If yes it clicks on it. When it clicks on it, another page is going to open and now i need a timer before searching for the close button of that page ...

Comment: huh?????? why do you need a timer?  are you executing this on the UI thread?

Comment: Yes, I want to learn as many things as a beginer can because I want to create a bot for a game. I started with something simple :)

Comment: Yes but putting in artificial pauses is not a good lesson to learn.

Comment: I know that exists different and better ways. For example using directly HTML code that page sends to you, but that game is using adobe flash and I am not sure if I can use another method.

Comment: so this is a code for a web page?  then there is no UI thread, your question is too vague and confusing.

Comment: Let me make it crystal clear and give you another example: I have a new c# form with a button. When I press the button I want ,after 5 seconds , the background to become another color. If you can modify my original post to become more clear, send me a version and I will update it to be more easy to find for others who have the same question :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Hiperkie FYI a timer in C# is a thing that runs a bit of code every x milliseconds on a background thread. You'd use it to run some function repeatedly. As Alex mentioned, you were looking for Thread.Sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a timer. you can use `Thread.Sleep`

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
success = search(Properties.Resources.close, screenshot(), out location);
```

Comment: why is this a solution?  placing an arbitrary sleep doesn't make sense and rarely solves the actual issue.  The question is very unclear.

Comment: placing a pause on the UI thread is definitely an anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Using Thread.Sleep is a bit brute force, but could be good enough for your purposes. (If the page doesn't load in how ever many seconds you sleep for this could still fail) If this is just an experiment, or something that only ever needs to run 1 thread at a time, that's fine.

Once you get a little more experienced with C# you'll probably want to try rewriting this to use Task and async/await. That way you can launch the execute method and have the system free up the main thread until execute is done. Using the await keyword will make the system continue with the code below the second execute to run on a background thread when execute is done. That way you don't freeze up the main foreground thread. Reading data from disk or network is a great application for asynchronous code.